Почему у Розенталя один и тот же пример написан в разных местах с разной пунктуацией? Как правильно?
В одном месте без запятой после "значит":
В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, а значит и сила приёма увеличивается во много раз.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122 п.5
В другом - с запятой:
В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, а значит, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз.
http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_12.htm#ppp_7 п.7

Правильно:
В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, а значит, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз.
Пояснение
Рассмотрим предложение: В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз.
Соединительный союз И связывает однородные члены: сила электромагнитного поля и сила приёма. Но в этом варианте неясно обозначена причинно-следственная связь, поэтому в заданном предложении используется вводное сочетание а значит. В грамматике это структурный элемент, который дифференцирует однородные члены. Вводное сочетание обособляется запятыми.
Такое решение дается у Розенталя в § 12. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами
 7. При наличии вводных слов, связывающих 
 однородные члены предложения, после последнего из 
 них запятая не ставится: В результате сила 
 электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, а 
 значит, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз; 
 Странный, если хотите — вызывающий тон неприятно 
 подействовал на окружающих. 

Такое же решение в ПАС  § 94
   Запятая после союза не ставится, если союз включается во 
   вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание 
   (изъятие вводного слова невозможно): В темном тумане 
   начали появляться обрывочные и бессвязные видения, 
   настолько бессвязные и далекие одно от другого, точно они 
   слетались ко мне от разных людей, а может быть, и не 
   только от людей (Расп.); Шла жизнь, может быть, веселая и 
   светлая, а может быть, скудная и молчаливая (Пауст.); 
   Быть самим собой — уже черта, свидетельствующая о 
   цельности, а значит, гармоничности (газ.); 

Другое решение дано  у Розенталя в § 25, пункт 5  Вводные слова и словосочетания. Там сочетание а значит приравнивается, вероятно,  к союзу а также и поэтому не обособляется.
   Однородный член предложения, стоящий после вводных слов а 
   значит, а следовательно, не обособляется (т. е. запятая 
   после него не ставится): В результате сила 
   электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, а значит и 
   сила приёма увеличивается во много раз; Эта схема, а 
   следовательно и весь проект в целом нуждается в 
   проверке.

Так как нужно выбирать правильное решение для конкретного предложения, то этот вариант приходится считать некорректным. Но это ведь Розенталь...
Или же возможны оба варианта: в первом случае соединительное значение союза И, а во втором — присоединительный оттенок в сочетании а также и (союз И ближе к присоединительному). Будем считать, что выбор зависит от контекста.

Спасибо! Мне кажется, во втором случае опечатка)

Опечатка? Скорее, творческая доработка)  У меня бумажный учебник Розенталя, изд. 2005 года, там только один  пример, но с запятой:  В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, а значит,  и сила приёма увеличивается во много раз;  После однор. члена запятая не нужна (нет обособления), а они заодно и здесь стерли.
